# same function but 2 different route and render 2 different templates

Tags: flask, jinja2

i want to know how use same function but 2 different route and render 2 different templates, the way i see is to do like this:

```
@app.route('/analysis_equipment_overview_approvalviewv2/<prelim_uid>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def analysis_equipment_overview_approvalviewv2(prelim_uid):
    #same logic here
    return render_template('template_1.html')

app.route('/analysis_equipment_overview_approvalview/<prelim_uid>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def analysis_equipment_overview_approvalview(prelim_uid):
    #same logic here
    return render_template('template_2.html')
```

is there any way to reduce the lines, especially when the logic is too long and avoid to write it twice?

Answer (score 0):

I find this way, but need clean code at pattern regex with constant.

```
@app.route('/analysis_equipment_overview_approvalviewv2/<prelim_uid>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/analysis_equipment_overview_approvalview/<prelim_uid>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def analysis_equipment_overview_approvalview(prelim_uid):
   #same logic here
   if re.search(r'/analysis_equipment_overview_approvalviewv2/', request.full_path):
      return render_template('template_2.html')
   return render_template('template_1.html')
```